# Use menuStrip and TabPages without Layout losings?

Tags: c#, menustrip

I've got a form with some tabPages.
Adding a MenuStrip to the form leads to the fact the the tabPages are cutted off on the right side.

I added an image for better understanding.

[image]

MenuStrip only includes an interrogation mark ( marked red in screenshot ).
As soon as I add this, the right edge of the tabs moves to the left ( by the width of the Menustrip, I suppose ) - marked with a blue line in the screenshot.

Whats's the right way to combine MenuStrip AND tabPages to get an layout as shown in the 2nd image?

[image]

Comment: Ensure that its Dock property is None, only Anchor it to the right.  You'll probably need to pick a bigger font for the TabControl to make the tabs tall enough to give the menu enough space.